# BigQuery: Not able to export to CSV

Tags: google-bigquery

I am able to import data from my google storage. However, having troubling exporting data to Google Cloud Storage CSV files through the web console. Data set is small, and I am not getting any specific reasons that cause the issue.

```
Extract9:30am
gl-analytics:glcqa.Device togs://glccsv/device.csv
Errors:
Unexpected. Please try again.
Job ID: job_f8b50cc4b4144e14a22f3526a2b76b75
Start Time: 9:30am, 24 Jan 2013
End Time: 9:30am, 24 Jan 2013
Source Table: gl-analytics:glcqa.Device
Destination URI: gs://glccsv/device.csv
```

Comment: Make sure `gs://glccsv` is an existing bucket on your cloud storage.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have a nested schema, which cannot be output to csv. Try setting the output format to JSON.

Note this bug has now been fixed internally, so after our next release you'll get a better error when this happens.